# Emulator not working: "CPU with EPT + UG needed"

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new to Android Studio, this is my first attempt at running an app. My computer is relatively slow and can't run HAXM so I'm using the ARM instead of the x86 build for the emulator. When I try running it, I get this error:

```
21:31   Gradle build finished in 15s 887ms

21:31   Emulator: WARNING: init: Missing WGL extension WGL_ARB_create_context

21:31   Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

21:31   Emulator: emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error

21:32   Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I've tried following instructions from multiple questions on this site, but nothing has worked for me so far. Is there a way to run the emulator or is it just not compatible with my computer? Thanks.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Buy new computer.

Answer (score 0):

The issues have to do with the specific device you're trying to emulate and the processor you have (intel core 2 or older)

To solve it:

Create a new emulator
Select the device you would like to emulate.
On the next page with the header "System Image" select the tab "other images"
Download and select an image that is listed as armeabi-v7a under the ABI column.
That image should run successfully with your processor.